# Accessing a Variable inForm1 from another class

Tags: c#, class, variables

I have been searching for some time now and can't really find a good solution to my problem.

I got a class (lets call it **TaskbarNotifier**) and my **Form1**

In **TaskbarNotifier** I got this:

```
private Form1 form = new Form1();
```

And later in that class I got this:

```
this.form.NotifiersCount = this.form.NotifiersCount - 1;
            switch (notifier)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.form.NewsShown = false;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.form.ThreadsSown = false;
                    break;
            }
```

now my problem is that when I do this I get a StackOverflow error at:

```
private Form1 form = new Form1();
```

Id there another better way to access variables in Form1 from another class?

Many thanks for reading :)

**----EDIT----**

Okay so in **Form1** constructor I got this:

```
    private ContextMenuStrip contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuItemExit = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuItemShow = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```

Which is where the stackoverflow actually starts.
But by removing:

```
private Form1 form = new Form1();
```

from **TaskbarNotifier** it don't throw any errors.

Comment: What's going on in the constructor of `Form1`? Are you sure that's where you're getting the stack overflow exception?

Comment: Actually.. no.. 
It's not where the stackoverflow happens, I forgot I had commented out some stuff to find the problem..

The stackoverflow starts in Form1
I will update my Question quickly :)

Comment: Where do you create `TaskbarNotifier`? Somewhere in `Form1`'s constructor no doubt?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET well now I just feel stupid xD

I was creating **TaskbarNotifier** before the form was all done -.-''

Comment: More importantly, if Form1 *ever* creates a `TaskbarNotifier` as part of construction, you will get an infinitely recursive loop here. I'll make these comments into an answer.

Comment: Instead of trying to manipulate Form1 directly, make TaskbarNotifier raise custom events that Form1 subscribes and responds to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, you are creating a `TaskbarNotifier` somewhere in the construction process of `Form1`.

That could happen if:

1. You explicitly wrote `var test = new TaskbarNotifier()` in the constructor
2. You dropped a control of that type onto the designer

In either case, `Form1` will construct a `TaskbarNotifier` which then constructs a `Form1` and, well, this happens a whole bunch of times and you get a Stack Overflow.

Make *sure* that the `TaskbarNotifier` is not created as part of `Form1` creation and the error will go away.